# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find_peaks_cwt' Process

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy import signal

 def get_sig_from_txt(directory_path, filename):
    with open(directory_path + '\\' + filename) as f:
       content = f.readlines()
       content = [int(x.strip()) for x in content]
       return np.array(content)


for filename in dirr:
    signal = get_sig_from_txt(path, filename)
    idx_peak = signal.find_peaks_cwt(signal, np.arange(1, 16))
```

I get the error :AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find_peaks_cwt' Process. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've *shadowed* your `signal` variable, which references the `scipy.signal` module.

Just assign the result of your function call to a different name:

```
for filename in dirr:
    sig = get_sig_from_txt(path, filename)
    idx_peak = signal.find_peaks_cwt(sig, np.arange(1, 16))
```